# How to hide rulers in a RichEditControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

I was wondering if there is a way to hide the rulers in a RichEditControl like the following:

```
<dxre:RichEditControl x:Name="richEditControl"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Margin="10"
                      Height="150"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Collapsed"
                      BarManager="{Binding ElementName=barManager1,
                                   Mode=OneTime}" />
```

Comment: can you edit its control template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment, I created a control without the rulers:

```
using DevExpress.Xpf.RichEdit;
(...)
    public class RulerlessRichEditControl : RichEditControl
(...)
            Options.HorizontalRuler.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditRulerVisibility.Hidden;
            Options.VerticalRuler.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditRulerVisibility.Hidden;
```